# Changing output of Prolog from a list to individual values

Tags: prolog

I want to alter the following code so that genN(3,R) outputs:
`R=0.`
`R=1.`
`R=2.`

Instead of a list `R=[0,1,2].` How would I go about completing this?

```
genN(0,[]).
genN(N,R) :-
    N > 0,
    N1 is N-1,
    genN(N1,R1),
    append(R1,[N1],R),
    !.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do :

```
gen(N, R) :-
    gen_one(N, 0, R).


gen_one(N, V, R) :-
    N > V,
    (   R = V; V1 is V+1, gen_one(N,V1,R)).
```

Comment: I often use the same names for predicates which are involved in the same process, I can name gen/3 gen_one  if you want !

Answer (score 2):

```
from0_upto(N, R) :-
    succ(N0, N),
    between(0, N0, R).
```

Consider that it is not trivial (not impossible either) to write your own version of `between/3` that behaves well in all corner cases. There are several attempts at this here on Stackoverflow, as well as an implementation in Prolog here: http://www.cs.otago.ac.nz/staffpriv/ok/pllib.htm (search for the string "between/3".

### The Bottom Line

If you need a list, generate a list. If you need solution upon backtracking, generate solutions upon backtracking.

Answer (score 2):

Use `genN/2` and `member/2` in conjunction, like this:

```
?- genN(3,Rs), member(R,Rs).
Rs = [0,1,2], R = 0 ;
Rs = [0,1,2], R = 1 ;
Rs = [0,1,2], R = 2.
```